# twig is_safe for simple function does not work

Tags: javascript, symfony, filter, escaping, twig

I have created a simple function that renders a template with js.
I'd like it to autoescape so I have set up the is_safe parameter to array(html') to not have to use the |raw filter

However it does not work, the jsis not escaped but rendered as plain text. If I use the |raw filters it works just fine.

How can I solve this ?

My simple function:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Extension\Twig;

use AppBundle\FoodMeUpParameters;
use AppBundle\Model\Interfaces\ViewCountInterface;
use ReflectionClass;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class FMUTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            'increaseViewCount' => new \Twig_SimpleFunction('increaseViewCount', array($this, 'increaseViewCount', array('is_safe' => array('html')))),
        );
    }


    public function increaseViewCount(ViewCountInterface $entity, $andFlush = true)
    {
        $reflect = new ReflectionClass($entity);

        $parameters = array(
            'short_name' => $reflect->getShortName(),
            'identifier' => $entity->getId(),
            'and_flush' => $andFlush
        );

        return $this->container->get('templating')->render(':Helper:increase_view_count.htmpl.twig', $parameters);
    }
}
```

My template :

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ path('increase_view_count') }}',
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {shortName: '{{ short_name }}', identifier: '{{ identifier }}', andFlush: '{{ and_flush }}'},
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The service declaration

```
fmu_twig_extension:
    class: %fmu_twig_extension.class%
    calls:
        - [setContainer, [@service_container]]
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

Answer (score 8):

You've included your `'is_safe'` options in your callback, rather than in the next (`$options`) argument.

You need to change....

```
'increaseViewCount' => new \Twig_SimpleFunction('increaseViewCount', array($this, 'increaseViewCount', array('is_safe' => array('html')))),
```

... to ...

```
'increaseViewCount' => new \Twig_SimpleFunction('increaseViewCount', array($this, 'increaseViewCount'), array('is_safe' => array('html'))),
```

Answer (score -1):

I suppose, in your case you should choose `'is_safe' => ['js']`. If it doesn't help for some reason, you can use definition from Twig's filter `raw`, where is [defined `is_safe` as `all`](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/1.x/lib/Twig/Extension/Escaper.php#L48).

Comment: well, changing this 'html' value to either 'js' or 'all' does not change anything : the js is displayed as plain text instead of being executed wheras using the raw filter does work... I'm still stuck here. Any idea of what to test to understand the issue the problem better?